# Angular Share Variable betwen $http.get and controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I can't pass the content of one variable inside `$http.get()` to outside of this method... it's always `undefined`.

I tested with `$rootScope`, but it didn't work.

```
controller('myControl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var content;

    $http.get('../Json/data.json').success(function (data, content) {
        content = data;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dataJson = "ERROR";
    });

    console.log(content); 
});
```

Comment: `content` is the second argument of your callback and also a global variable, that's not right.

Comment: Make sure you use a console.log to test it, rather than evaluating in chrome dev tools, since sometimes says it's undefined when it really isn't.

Comment: Don't pass content in your parameters for success function. This is a global variable.

Comment: ok, but how I can get the value I get inside of $http, outside of this method??

Comment: Is not duplicated.. I want to do a async peticion with $http in ANGULAR, like in this way: Promises in AngularJS...http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

- The `content` parameter in your success handler is *shadowing* the `content` variable in your controller.
- You are trying to write `content` to the console before it has a value. This will not work because `$http.get()` is asynchronous.

To fix these problems:

- Remove the `content` parameter. It serves no purpose.
- Use the `content` variable *inside* your `success` callback.

```
controller('myControl', function ($scope, $http) {
    var content;

    $http.get('../Json/data.json').success(function (data) {
        content = data;

        console.log(content);
        $scope.dataJson = content;
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.dataJson = "ERROR";
    });
});
```

Comment: I only use this console to watch the value, but the final purpouse is use something like that: $scope.dataJson = this.content; I can't remove the content because I need to get the content outside...

Comment: @llena8583 Ok, if you want to assign it to the scope, then do so (see my edit). I don't see a problem. _"I can't remove the content because I need to get the content outside"_ No, what you were doing was serving no purpose whatsoever. Giving your `success` callback a `content` parameter doesn't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't wait for asynchronous `$http.get()` to finish so `console.log()` will always print out `undefined`.

Second, maybe you could think about using `then()` rather than `success()`.

http://bit.ly/18xIHio

The following should work just fine for you.

```
/* JS */
app.controller('myControl', function($http) {
    var ctrl = this;

    $http.get('http://www.data.fi/data.json').then(function (response) {
        ctrl.content = response; // use response.data to get the payload
    }).catch(function (error) {
        ctrl.content = error;
    }).finally(function() {
        console.log(ctrl.content); 
    });
});

<!-- HTML -->
<div ng-controller="myControl as ctrl">{{ ctrl.content | json }}</div>
```

Comment: Don't think that `this` will point to what you want in your example here.

Comment: Thanks, I was testing your code, but the problem is I need to get the value of the response out of the $http.get, for use like: $scope.dataJson = this.content; I'm using MorrisJs to load wiith this data a Chart, but I try to use inside this scope but didn't work... works outside of this $http this is the reasson because I want to get this value outside. With your code the content is always undefined, I check that directly in the Debugger from Firefox

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass content in your parameters for success function. This is a global variable. Passing it would create scoping issues.
Also use console.log both inside success function and outside it.